# Populating Grails TextField with JS value - Beginner

Tags: javascript, grails

My JavaScript method should set value to the Grails TextField. How can i do this ?

JS function

```
$("p").click(function(){

            console.log('THE '+url);
            alert(url);
          });
```

Grails HTML code

```
<g:textField name="directions" maxlength="50" required="" value="${HOW DO I GET THE VALUR HERE FROM THE ABOVE JS FUNCTION }"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your javascript, try this

```
$("#directions").val(url);
```